# Add Image Uploader In Admin Panel

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have created a custom taxonomy and I want to be able to upload an image while creating or editing my custom taxonomy terms. 
The twist is, I want the uploaded image to be saved in an "images" folder inside my home directory (public_html/images). 
The default WordPress uploader uploads the images in uploads folder inside wp-content & I don't want to change that.
Also, I don't need to save the path in the database or return it anywhere. I just want the image to be saved in that specific folder. Rest all is handled by other functions.

Is there any way I can do this without playing with any of WP's core files.

Thanks in advance.